# I cannot fix node vulnerabilities even with npm audit fix --force

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

> Dear all,
> after trying several times to fix vulnerabilities with npm, it still gives the messages below; Do you have any solution to fix these problems? thank you for your help.

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix
PS D:\openclassroom\P7\P7groupomania\backend> npm audit fix
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

up to date, audited 231 packages in 2s

## npm audit report

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service in glob-parent - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/glob-parent
chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
node_modules/chokidar
nodemon  >=1.3.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
Depends on vulnerable versions of update-notifier
node_modules/nodemon

got  <11.8.5
Severity: moderate
Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/got
package-json  <=6.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of got
node_modules/package-json
latest-version  0.2.0 - 5.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of package-json
node_modules/latest-version
update-notifier  >=0.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of latest-version
node_modules/update-notifier

7 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 3 high)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix
PS D:\openclassroom\P7\P7groupomania\backend>

Answer (score 2):

I just received the got vulnerability from github dependabot, and resolved it by:

1. It looks like it's a nested dependency of nodemon. https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/2023 Which they are going to fix by removing their dependency.
2. It's for nodemon, which is run during dev not on production, so you could and I did ignore it as it's not vulnerable code :D.
3. Other option - maybe set up an override for got in your package.json? or wait till nodemon next update?

Note: Sometimes npm audit fix does nothing, I always assumed it was because it couldn't figure out how to fix it, e.g. in nodemon it's a nested dependency so might struggle? Also npm audit fix sometimes fixes something by upgrading but that brakes something else, so I don't have 100% faith in it. (No bugs or articles to back this up, just anecdotal evidence).